# how to change webview2 user data folder in tauri?

Tags: rust, user-defined-functions, webview2, tauri

Is there anyway to change user data folder in edge webview2 in tauri ?
I have to change environenment variable WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER before tauri initialization. but it does work in sometime, so that it is better change it via some interface.

here is my code:

```
    let udf = xxxxxx; //some folder generated for each user.
    env::set_var("WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER", udf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use tauri::WebView2;
fn main() {
    let mut webview = WebView2::new();
    let udf = xxxxxx; //some folder generated for each user.
    webview.set_user_data_folder(udf);
    webview.run().unwrap();
    }
```

You can call this method before calling the run method of the WebView2 struct to set the user data folder before the webview is initialized.